# Подгрузка контента

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Этот скрипт подгружает контент без перезагрузки страницы. В функции указана подгрузка в один div, КАК СДЕЛАТЬ ПОДГРУЗКУ В РАЗНЫЕ div ОДНОВРЕМЕННО НА ОДНОЙ СТРАНИЦЕ? Спасибо всем!

```
function showContent(link) { 
    var cont = document.getElementById('menu'); 
    var loading = document.getElementById('loading'); 
    cont.innerHTML = loading.innerHTML;   
    var http = createRequestObject(); 
    if( http )  
    { http.open('get', link); 
        http.onreadystatechange = function ()  
        {   if(http.readyState == 4)  
            {   cont.innerHTML = http.responseText;  }    } 
        http.send(null);  } 
    else  
    {  document.location = link;   }   } 
// ajax объект
function createRequestObject()  
{  try { return new XMLHttpRequest() } 
    catch(e)  
    {  try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP') } 
        catch(e)  
        {   try { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') } 
            catch(e) { return null; }   } } }
```

Подгружаемая страница при клике

```
  <a href="#"onClick="showContent('http://prorab-service.ru/new/masters/masters.php')"><div id="country">Выбрать страну</div></a>
```

Подгружаемая Страница по умолчанию.

```
showContent('http://prorab-service.ru/new/masters/masters.php')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showContent(id, link) { 
  var cont = document.getElementById(id); 
  ...
}

showContent('menu', 'http://prorab-service.ru/new/masters/masters.php');
showContent('menu1', 'http://prorab-service.ru/new/masters/masters1.php');
showContent('menu2', 'http://prorab-service.ru/new/masters/masters2.php');
```

*Update*

```
<a href="#" onClick="showContentForCountry()"><div id="country">Выбрать страну</div></a>

function showContentForCountry() {
  showContent('menu', 'http://prorab-service.ru/new/masters/masters.php');
  showContent('menu1', 'http://prorab-service.ru/new/masters/masters1.php');
  showContent('menu2', 'http://prorab-service.ru/new/masters/masters2.php');
}
```

Comment: Как подгружать при клике на ссылку?